# How to fill the email field on checkout page (guest)?

Tags: magento2, checkout, quote, guest-checkout

I have developed a function to request the e-mail from the guest before going to checkout, which I keep inside the Quote of the current session, so far nice.

But when you go to checkout, the field e-mail is empty, I need to be able to fill in the e-mail field with this value.

I have accessible the value of the quote email, the problem is to write it in the email field of the checkout.

What should be the right way?

Comment: do you put custom email field, right?

Comment: I request the email on a page before checkout, this email is stored in the quote table in the record associated with the current session of the client. I need to auto fill in the checkout the email field with this value.

Comment: Where you save that email?

Comment: “this email is stored in the quote table (database) in the record associated with the current session of the client” The problem is write into email field of checkout.